# How do you style a fieldset with the legend inline with the other children

Tags: html, css

Can anybody tell me how to style the following fieldset so the legend and the radiobuttons are all on the one line?

```
<fieldset>
   <legend>Are you from planet earth?</legend>
   <label><input type="radio" name="answer"/>Yes</label>
   <label><input type="radio" name="answer"/>No</label>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CSS:

```
legend {
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: This is the best answer, but I would suggest adding `input {vertical-align: top;}` so that the legend aligns properly with the input labels.

Answer (score 0):

This will work.  Just float them left.  Probably a better way to do it, but it works.

```
<fieldset>
   <legend style='float:left'>Are you from planet earth?</legend>
   <label style='float:left'><input type="radio" name="answer"/>Yes</label>
   <label style='float:left'><input type="radio" name="answer"/>No</label>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: It's a general best practice to avoid inline styles, as it prohibits extensibility.

Answer (score 0):

The answers are a bit stale. `float: left;` will work, but can cause other layout issues and requires clearing the float on subsequent containers.

Nowadays, `flexbox` or CSS Grid Layout have excellent modern browser support.

Comment: Unfortunately, Fieldset and legends do not listen to flexbox and grid the way you would expect. Even in 2023, the `float:left` option is probably still the best and the easiest. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67268971/how-can-a-fieldset-be-set-to-flex-so-that-the-legend-is-on-the-left-of-the-conte