# How can a fieldset be set to flex so that the legend is on the left of the content?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, safari, fieldset

I want to format the fieldset/legend with flex so that the legend is on the left side of the content of the fieldset. I know I can `float:left` the legend, but somehow in Safari 14 this does not work. How can I get around this issue?

```css
fieldset {
  display: flex;
  align-items: baseline;
}

legend {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 250px
}

button {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>Should float in line with content</legend>
  <button>Content</button>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set parent `display: inline`

```css
fieldset {
  display: inline;
}
legend {
  float: left;
  width: 250px
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend align="left">Should float in line with content</legend >
  Content
</fieldset>
```

Comment: The problem is in Chrome 90, my example looks correct and I'd love to keep the `<legend>` tag, as it is more accessible than just `<div>`.

Comment: I just updated the answer, try it out. Works for me on safari!

Comment: My problem is, that inline solution works as long as you have just a single word and enough space. But the content could be more than that. I updated my example.